# mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time. Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, configuration

When I'm trying to install MySQL 5.5 community edition on my Ubuntu 10.04 [by compiling the source code](https://serverfault.com/questions/435932/whats-the-mysql-5-5-compilation-configuration-arguments-on-ubuntu-10-04), I met the following problem:

```
$ fg % 1
sudo ../bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr/local/mysql_community_5.5/data --user=mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf
```

> [sudo] password for linnan:
>
> Sorry, try again. [sudo] password for linnan:   121023 09:26:21
>   mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time. Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
>   Internal program error (non-fatal):  unknown logging method
>   '/usr/local/mysql_community_5.5/log/mysql.log'  121023 09:26:21
>   mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
>   Internal program error (non-fatal):  unknown logging method
>   '/usr/local/mysql_community_5.5/log/mysql.log'  121023 09:26:22
>   mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
>   121023 09:26:23 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu.pid ended

It seems that the problem is related to log configuration. I've noticed a bugfix related to this problem: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50083
But I still have no idea how to solve it.

The relative content in /etc/my.cnf:

> [mysqld] port            = 3306 socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
>   skip-external-locking key_buffer_size = 384M max_allowed_packet = 1M
>   table_open_cache = 512 sort_buffer_size = 2M read_buffer_size = 2M
>   read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
>   thread_cache_size = 8 query_cache_size = 32M
>   `#` Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency thread_concurrency = 8 character-set-server=utf8
>   **[mysqld-safe]**
>   basedir=/usr/local/mysql_community_5.5
>   datadir=/usr/local/mysql_community_5.5/data

mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf: 
   /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf:

> [mysqld_safe]
>   syslog